# How to prove that not all recursive sets are in $\mathsf{P}$?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

I am interested in finding simple proof (without time hierarchy theorem) of the following fact:

To show that there is a recursive set that is not in class $\mathsf{P}$.

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to avoid the time hierarchy theorem?

Comment: My intuition tells me that it is quite likely that the only way we know how to do this is using the time hierarchy theorem, but I would be happy to be proven wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class $\mathsf P$ is **effectively enumerable**: If we define
$$ A_k = \{n\mid \text{Turing machine number $k$ accepts $n$ in at most $n^k+k$ steps}\}$$
then every set in $\mathsf P$ is $A_k$ for some $k$.

This works because every real polynomial is pointwise smaller than something of the form $x^k+k$, and every Turing machine has (in effect) arbitrarily large indices -- namely, we can add unreachable states to it until the index is as large as we want it. (We could avoid this reasoning at the cost of introducing a tupling function and corresponding projections).

Now we can diagonalize to find
$$ D = \{ n \mid \text{Turing machine number $n$ does not accept $n$ in at most $n^n+n$ steps}\} $$
which is clearly recursive, but by construction differs from all the $A_k$s and so is not in $\mathsf P$.

Whether this proof is significantly different from just applying the time hierarchy theorem is, I suppose, in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: In the details of your argument, I think you are confusing the size of the input to the Turing Machine with its numerical value viewed using the binary representation (say).

Comment: @RobArthan: I thought of adding extra details to handle that, but decided it would just obscure the central idea. Taken literally, what we have here is a set that is not even decidable in time poynomial in $2^{\text{size of input}}$ which, though stronger than we need, still meets the specification.